# Trouble with converting Json in Java

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to read in a somewhat complex json string and I'm having problems with nested items and how to retrieve them.

My java code looks like the following

```
String longJson = "{'Patient': {'Name': {'Given': 'FirstName','Family': 'LastName'},'Gender': 'Female','DOB': '1980-07-04T00:00:00.0000000','AgeInYears': 36,'MartialStatus': 'Single', 'Race': 'Race','Ethnicity': 'Ethnicity','Class': 'Inpatient','Address': {'StreetAddress': 'StreetAddress','City': 'City','State': 'State','ZipCode': 'ZipCode', 'Country': 'Country'}}}";

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    PrescriptionReq sample = null;
    sample = gson.fromJson(longJson, PrescriptionReq.class);


    String firstName = sample.getPatient().getName().getGiven();
    //String firstName = sample.patient.name.getGiven();
    System.out.println("Testing: "+ firstName);
```

When I run either approach I get a null point exception

Here is the Json in a more readable view

```
        {
        "Patient": {
            "Name": {
                "Given": "FirstName",
                "Family": "LastName"
            },
            "Gender": "Female",
            "DOB": "1980-07-04T00:00:00.0000000",
            "AgeInYears": 36,
            "MartialStatus": "Single",
            "Race": "Race",
            "Ethnicity": "Ethnicity",
            "Class": "Inpatient",
            "Address": {
                "StreetAddress": "StreetAddress",
                "City": "City",
                "State": "State",
                "ZipCode": "ZipCode",
                "Country": "Country"
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are my classes:

```
public class PrescriptionReq {
private Patient patient;

public Patient getPatient(){
    return patient;
}

public class Patient {
    Name name;
    Address address;

    public Name getName(){
        return name;
    }
    //Other variables
   }

public class Name {
    private String Given;
    private String Family;

    public String getGiven() {
        return Given;
    }

    public String getFamily() {
        return Family;
    }

   }
}
```

I'm not sure if I am storing the json wrong or retrieving it wrong.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What part is null?

Comment: String firstName = sample.getPatient().getName().getGiven();
is returning a null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Your field names aren't matching your JSON, and hence you're getting back a `PrescriptionReq` object with a `null` patient field.

Off the top of my head, I can think of a couple ways to fix this:

- Change the name of the variable to match the JSON field

  ```
  public class PrescriptionReq {
      // have to rename Patient class to avoid name collision
      private PRPatient Patient;
  ...
  ```
- Add a `@SerializedName` annotation to tell Gson what the "real" field name is

  ```
  public class PrescriptionReq {
      @SerializedName("Patient")
      private Patient patient;
  ...
  ```

Of course you'll also need to do this for the `name` field in the `Patient` class, as well as anything in `Address` you're having problems with.